# Hiding the Info Window of a business result in an iframe embedded Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I am attempting to embed a google map into a page of a website using google maps' iframe capabilities (so that I can avoid having to add things within the head and inside the body tag of the page)

When I create the iframe code, everything is fine except for the fact that the info window associated with the pin is opening by default when the page loads.

I'm wondering if anyone has successfully overridden this behavior.  I've found a few posts describing how to do it for a geocoded address but **not for a specific place of business** (it seems the attributes are different)

Code:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Madison+Square+Garden+New+York+NY&amp;hl=en&amp;cd=1&amp;ei=PoNXS-hcmuLJBNfexZUI&amp;sig2=dFymmpNhsjY6dEvjphBbPQ&amp;sll=40.731053,-73.951703&amp;sspn=0.127506,0.130247&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=5487804314630162138&amp;ved=0CCUQpQY&amp;hq=Madison+Square+Garden+New+York+NY&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.750354,-73.992491&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

---

(This is the suggestion I found on 'net that does not seem to work for a specific place of business: http://www.sugarwebdev.co.uk/blog/hide-or-remove-the-info-window-on-an-embedded-google-map/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the solution posted in your question, using the iframe code you provided and it [worked fine](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo19). I added:

```
&amp;iwloc=near
```

right after the 'output=embed' at the end.

Comment: @Cannonada ... thanks so much ... I tried adding the iwloc property in a couple of different places, including the suggestion of the link I included (which is somewhere in the middle) but, for whatever reason, never at the end.

Comment: For the sake of prosperity ... the code is:
<iframe width="425" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Madison+Square+Garden+New+York+NY&amp;hl=en&amp;cd=1&amp;ei=PoNXS-hcmuLJBNfexZUI&amp;sig2=dFymmpNhsjY6dEvjphBbPQ&amp;sll=40.731053,-73.951703&amp;sspn=0.127506,0.130247&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=5487804314630162138&amp;ved=0CCUQpQY&amp;hq=Madison+Square+Garden+New+York+NY&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.750354,-73.992491&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>

Comment: No problem :) Glad I was able to help.

Comment: This has stopped working. Seems Google changed something. Has anyone got any idea on the new way to fix this?