# How to remove google map address box by keeping marker in iframe?

Tags: google-maps

I am using google map iframe embedded at my site and the code is

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1085.7167751755183!2d90.3674116098519!3d23.750896076109!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3755bf51d563ecbb%3A0x1c5247613aecf1e8!2zS2lkcyAmIE1vbXMg4KaV4Ka_4Kah4Ka4IOCmj-CmqOCnjeCmoSDgpq7gpq4!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1493197219814&output=embed&iwloc=near" width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

I want to remove address box from it and for that I have followed a solution
[How to remove box from new Google Maps embeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554575/how-to-remove-box-from-new-google-maps-embeds/37083353#37083353) rawnewdlz solution. But the solution also removes the marker pointer. I need to keep that.

Please need help!

Comment: Are you trying to acheive something mentioned at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode.

Comment: Just want to remove the white box upper left containing address.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed a pattern just a few characters had to be removed.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2624.9916256937586!2d2.2922926160647448!3d48.858370079287475!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1493209164303" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have removed the following portion: 1m2!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d%3A0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!2sEiffel+Tower!5e0!

Comment: I have tried the code. But it also remove the pointer. I need the pointer marker to indicate location.